# CSS side by side divs with fixed link at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I got a problem when positioning three divs side by side.

Those three divs contain normal text but also have a link at the bottom.

```
<div id="parent">
    <h1>Description</h1>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
        <a href="#">Bottom</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata</p>
        <a href="#">Bottom</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
        <a href="#">Bottom</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

To get this responsive, the items are `inline-block` with a width of 32%.

```
div#parent {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#parent div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Now the problem is, that when I change the window size, the height of the items are different. I want the links at the bottom of the items to be at the same position, like this:
[image: Yes]

But actual it looks like this:
[image: No]

I used JavaScript to set those items to the same height, but how can I get theese links to the same position? I know this can be done by setting the item to `position: relative;` and the a to `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` but then `text-align: center;` doesn't work anymore.

[I made a JSFiddle for you to understand my problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/vgxocqw7/)

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You should use Flexbox for this. Check out this tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You could use one div with the text and one div with the link and place those 2 divs into your <div class="item">. You give the text div a standard height and the links will be at the same position.

Comment: but he doesn't know the height of the text - it is a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Flex can do this very easily but with some what less browser support. Another way is using `display: table`, which have very good support (down to IE8), at the end you find a sample using that.

One more way, thinking in the terms of "rows", is like this, where there is no  *absolute position*, *no script* and keep your links at the bottom, all centered.

**Update**

As requested, and to make it more responsive, I added a media query.

Run the snippet in full page and resize the browser to see it in action.

To be noted though, this is still a "without using flex" solution.

**Update 2**

Added a `display: table`

```css
#parent {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#parent div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
#parent div.item ~ div.item {
    margin-left: 1%;
}

#parent .contents a {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #parent div.item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #parent .contents a {
    display: inline;
  }
  #parent .links a {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="wrapper contents">
        <h1>Description</h1>
        <div class="item">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea duo rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata</p>
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper links">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The table version

```css
#parent {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#parent div.item {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#parent div.item ~ div.item {
    padding-left: 1%;
}
#parent div.item a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #parent {
    display: block;
  }
  #parent div.item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Description</h1>
        <div class="item">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea duo rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata</p>
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p>sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</p>
            <a href="#">Bottom</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvote for table hint using css. A good and structured way to display data.

Comment: Good idea, but sadly I can't use this. Im using media queries, and currently I use `display: block;` if the screen is to small to order them among themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for a solution **without** `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` I give you the following approach.

What you can do is that you wrap up your content containers into another div-container and insert the link after your content container. You would get a pseudo structure like that:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        Text etc...
    </div>
    <a href="target...">Linktext</a>
</div>
```

For every three of your content containers. Working with your javascript resizeFunction the links are on the same height all the time.

Note that your `div.content-wrapper` is `display:inline-block;` now, but your `div.content` are not.

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2:** Since you asked for a solution without `position:relative/absolute`, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33255289/3338286) instead.

**My old (kinda invalid) answer:**

I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vgxocqw7/1/

new css:

```
div#parent div.item {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
    position:relative;
}
div#parent div.item a.bottom{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

and also added `class="bottom"` to your links

you might need to do some work on positioning of the "bottom"-links, they are not quite centered

**EDIT: Removed JS**

https://jsfiddle.net/vgxocqw7/5/

Comment: with this solution the javascript can be removed.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch thanks, i updated the post and the fiddle. didnt even realize there was js

Answer (score 0):

If you make equal heights with javascript for the div.item, then:

```
div#parent div.item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

div#parent div.item a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code the div will be **centered** at the bottom even while using `position:absolute`:

```
div#parent div.item {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    position: relative;
    min-height:160px;

}

a {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vgxocqw7/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Update CSS as below:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgxocqw7/8/)

```
div#parent div.item {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 32%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;        
}

div#parent div.item a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```